# I have a comment model on home page, but it does not automatically detect which post I am writing my comment amongst all posts

Tags: django

So the error I am encountering. Pk can not be recognized. Because there are too many posts on the main page. I have been trying to solve this by changing pk to id, changing my models of comments many ways. But there is no use

The real reason is that ı have to go into detailview so that page can easily detect. Oh look he is here on this page path('post//', PostDetailView.as_view(), name ="post-detail"), so we can save this comment on a spesific post.pk. But I want everything is connected

NameError at /
name 'pk' is not defined

```
class PostListView(ListView, DetailView):   
    model = Post
    template_name = "blog/home.html" # <app>/model>_viewtype>html
    context_object_name = "posts"
    paginate_by = 15
    template = loader.get_template('blog/post_detail.html')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-id")
        gallerys = Gallery.objects.all()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter()
        likes = Post.objects
        post = request.POST.get(Post)

        # cnc = Contact.objects.all()
        today = timezone.now().date()
        is_liked = False
        # if posts.likes.filter(id = request.user.id).exists():
        #   is_liked = True
        comment_form = CommentForm(request.POST or None)
        context = { 'posts': posts, "likes": likes,"comment_form":comment_form, "comments": comments, "gallerys":gallerys, "today": today}

        # return render(request, "blog/home.html")

        return render(request, "blog/home.html", context)



    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = PostForm()
        posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-id")
        data2 = Gallery.objects.all()
        comments = Comment.objects.filter()
        likes = Post.objects
        today = timezone.now().date()
        is_liked = False
        comment_form = CommentForm(self.request.POST or None )
        if comment_form.is_valid():
            form.instance.author = request.user
            post = form.save(commit = False)
            content = request.POST.get("content")
            # post = request.POST.get(Post)
            post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk = pk)

            comment = Comment.objects.create(post = post, author = request.user, content= content)
            comment.save()
            return render(request, "blog/home.html", {'posts': posts, "likes": likes,"comment_form":comment_form, "comments": comments, "today": today})

        else:
            comment_form = CommentForm()
        return render(request, "blog/home.html", {'posts': posts, "likes": likes,"comment_form":comment_form, "comments": comments, "gallerys":gallerys, "today": today})


class Post(models.Model):


    STATUS_CHOICES = {
        ("draft", "Draft"),
        ("published", "Published"),
    }
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.CASCADE )
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 100, null=True, blank=True,  default="Başlık")
    content = models.TextField(blank =True, null=True, default = "Enter your content")
    .....
    objects = models.Manager


    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.pub_date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("post-detail", kwargs={"pk": self.pk})

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.__str__()
        return super(Post, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    #it will show not <Question: Question object (1)> but the authors name or title
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk}"




class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name='content', default="Başlık")
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    # Name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, default="Başlık")
    # Email = models.EmailField(max_length = 100)
    # Body = models.TextField()
    # Active = models.BooleanField(default = True)
    # Parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete = models. CASCADE, null = True, blank = True, related_name = "replies")

    objects = models.Manager


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.pk}"

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse("blog:post-detail", kwargs={
            'pk': self.pk
        })


#blog app
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name ="blog-home"),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name ="user-posts"),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name ="post-detail"),

    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(model=Post, success_url=('/')), name ="post-create"),

    path('contact/', contact.as_view(), name ="blog-contact"),

    url(r'^$', views.HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),


]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that, it is more like migration issue than coding problem. Django should provide immigration issue explanations, because it is such a great starting language and should be more userfriendly.

After deleting the post in database and migrating without deleting the previous ones, it still thinks PK is there on the post. However PK of user is deleted on the relational post, it errs. Anyways this may help:

```
python3 manage.py migrate --fake youtubeapi python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb

python manage.py makemigrations youtubeapi python manage.py makemigrations youtubeapi --empty python manage.py migrate youtubeapi zero python manage.py makemigrations youtubeapi python manage.py squashmigrations youtubeapi 0001_initial python manage.py squashmigrations youtubeapi 0001 python manage.py squashmigrations youtubeapi 0001_squashed_0001_initial
```